# Meaning of the cat in the opening scene of Godfather I?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

I am aware that the cat was a spur of the moment idea of Coppola; he explains in his commentary track for the movie that he had seen the cat running around and handed it to Brando who liked animals and took to the cat.

It occurs to me that the playing with the cat is sort of out of character for Vito who if anything is a serious man and certainly is discussing serious matters.

While Coppola in the commentary does not say this, could it be that the subtext of the scene is that Vito is showing those visiting him that if he wants to play with a cat in while discussing these matters, he can and too bad if you don't like it.

On the other hand, it seems clear that Vito would not have played with a cat when meeting Sollozzo and certainly not when meeting with the other heads of families.

Answer (score 2):

[As explained here](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/the-godfather-marlon-brandos-cat-was-a-non-scripted-stray.html/):

> Coppola thought the innocent cat would show the softer side of the character Vito Corleone. The cat also became a symbol for the hidden claws Vito would later have.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it means, "I can play with my cat whenever I want to."  Vito cares deeply about people.  He loves his wife and children.  He helped that poor woman in Godfather II who was having her rent hiked by her landlord.  He has shown his softer side on many occasions, but people also know he can be ruthless when it's necessary.